# Is it enough to just close the Socket or should I close the streams as well?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

When I establish a connection with my server via TCP Socket I use the following code to communicate:

```
Socket socket = ...

NetworkStream ns = new NetworkStream(socket);

StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ns);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ns);
```

now ... is it enough to just do `socket.Close();` or is it better to do:

```
sw.Close();
sr.Close();
ns.Close();
socket.Close();
```

Does anyone know what is the most appropriate way to clean up / close / release the socket?

And also, should I do a `Dispose()` on each variable defined above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried anything?

[`NetworkStream.Close()` reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.close.aspx):

> Closes the current stream and releases any resources (such as sockets and file handles) associated with the current stream. Instead of calling this method, ensure that the stream is properly disposed.

So:

```
using (NetworkStream ns = new NetworkStream(socket))
{
     // Your code
}
```

Comment: Never thought of this. Thank you CodeCaster,

Answer (score 0):

You should close the output stream. That will flush it, and close the other stream and the socket. Don't close those yourself, or if you must, close them after the output stream. Otherwise you can lose data.